# Save file in android, so the user can't read

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, android-resources, android-assets

I am developing an app in android where it download image files and use it as app resource. I want to save the file in a directory so that user can't see this as media files shown in gallery. I just need to know the specific directory where i can save the file and the user wouldn't able to see it.

Comment: The application's private storage area might meet that need to a limited extent, provided the device doesn't get rooted and provided your app doesn't change the permissions.

Comment: but I have a huge number images as resource... then what would I do?...is there any chance to use the application package directory to store and meet my need??

Comment: @mostafa imran no any give you ready  made code dear witch one i do you do this type i done it very well.just try then say me i help u

Comment: You cannot write to the application package itself, but there is a private directory for each application which you can write to and which others cannot read unless you grant public access.  Please spend some time with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)  You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Answer (score 3):

Android would automatically scan all folders on external storage for media files. If you don't want your image files to show in the gallery, maybe you could add some extension like ".myapp", this way cheats the scanner.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that you had used the external storage qualifier

Answer (score 1):

Just Simple apply your own logic.
when u read the file from internet is byte format.
and after right in to sdcard.

this time just change the some byte of read file.and store this byte in some place like a sharepreference,Static varibale anything.and when you read file and display else play then change the same byte agian and replace this byte with orignal.this call incrypt and decrept.
it`s work dear i do for image file.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a file named `.nomedia` in the directory you want to exclude from `MediaScanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to save your image in a Database as a BLOB.
With this you are 100% sure that only your application can access it.

Comment: yap it is a solution... but I don't think it's efficient for huge list of images...

Comment: Actually that is untrue.  Database files are not necessarily private, though if created in the application's private directory they are by default.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, please do elaborate. How can other application access a private database.

Comment: Databases are not necessarily private.  Just as with any other files, it depends on where they are created and what permissions they are given, so switching to a database changes nothing.  Also "private" anything is only such to the degree that the device security model is intact.